# dismissing a UIPickerView once the user selected all rows

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components where the user can select a font and a font size.

I want to dismiss the view once the user has selected both.

Can I somehow do this using the `didSelectRow:inComponent` method?

Comment: what you want exactly ?? you need to get selected item from both components when user select from any one ?? and also hide pickerView too ?

Comment: Exothug you can refer the below code given by me

Comment: You can check edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you record the `component` that is provided to the method then when all of your components have had a selection made you can dismiss.

Note that users may not like it very much and adding a toolbar above the picker with a done button might work better.

---

I would suggest creating a container view to hold the picker and the toolbar (subviews), then show / hide the container view with whatever animations you like (instead if where you currently show the picker view). The picker and the toolbar don't need to be linked in any way, just laid out nicely in the container.

Comment: How would i add a toolbar like that? I'm still fairly new in obj-c.

also, thanks for haunting my questions with all these amazing answers today

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you

```
     UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    action.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIPickerView *pickerFromage=[[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0 , 0)];
    UIToolbar *pickerAgeToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerAgeToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerAgeToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(PickerDoneClick)];
    [doneBtn setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [pickerAgeToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    pickerFromage.delegate=self;
    pickerFromage.dataSource=self;
    pickerFromage.tag=value;
    pickerFromage.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;

    [action addSubview:pickerAgeToolbar];
    [action addSubview:pickerFromage];
    [action showInView:self.view];
    [action setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 464)];`


     -(void)PickerDoneClick{
        [action dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
            action=nil;

}
```

Comment: this just crashes for some reason

Comment: stringcountryid is unknown to the compiler as well

Comment: have u took the pickerview in xib

Comment: the pickerview needs to be rendered completely programatically after clicking a button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33623/discussion-between-sravan-kumar-and-exothug)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

Take a UIView in xib and then add a UIPickerView and a toolbar with UIButton on it. Give the delegate to the UIPickerView and assign an action to the UIButton. Take an outlet of UIView and in your implementation file(ie. .m file). Hide the UIView and assign the frame to the bottom of the screen. Lets say you have named the view as myPickerView.

```
myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds),
CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds),
CGRectGetWidth(myPickerView.frame),
CGRectGetHeight(myPickerView.frame));

myPickerView.hidden = YES;
```

After doing this you can animate the view from bottom to upwards by setting the frame again in animation block, and can also unhide it.

When you press done, again animate the view and set the frame as above.

Below is the code for animating

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(UIButton *)sender {

self.myPickerView.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
[self.myPickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
100, 
CGRectGetWidth(self.myPickerView.frame), 
CGRectGetHeight(self.myPickerView.frame))];

}];
}
```

action for done button:

```
-(IBAction)doneClicked:(id)sender {

self.myPickerView.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.myPickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds),
                                           CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds),
                                           CGRectGetWidth(self.myPickerView.frame),
                                           CGRectGetHeight(self.myPickerView.frame))];

}];
```

}

Hope this helps.